# Reusing UMAP transformation

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I have this use case:
I want to apply a dimension reduction with UMAP to a initial dataset of high-dimension vectors (100d), and later, in second place, have the oppurtinity to add new data points from the original space (so a vector of 100d), that will be transformed according to the first transformation (aka without recalculating the umap vectors for the first N vectors).
Is it possible? Does UMAP have a transformation matrix ( or similar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UMAP has a transform *method* that can achieve this. Note that this is a somewhat expensive computation, and not almost instant as it can be with, for example, PCA. See the [UMAP documentation](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transform.html) for more details.

If you need a very fast transform method for new data then I would encourage you to look at [Parametric UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parametric_umap.html) which uses a neural network to learn a direct mapping from input space to the embedding space and provides very efficient transforms.